# SAML Passing a JWT token from the API to the SPA application

Tags: jwt, saml, single-page-app

We are trying to implement the SAML 2.0 protocol and I stumbled upon a problem related to passing the token from the API to the client SPA application.

The authentication flow goes like this: the client is redirected to the IdP application where he enters his credentials. Then the IdP performs the POST request to the API (the service provider) with all the security assertions.

Now the API knows that the user is authenticated, so it would like to pass a JWT token to the client app, which will use the token for future requests.

The question is: how do I perform the last step? I could just issue a redirect with the access token as the query string so that the client application will read it and store it in the local storage but this means that the access token might be logged in the access logs. Do I have another way of solving this?

Maybe set the JWT as a cookie and use a CSRF mechanism ?